# Gtk-ERROR **: GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported The program has unexpectedly finished

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, qt-creator

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Qtcreator, al instalar opencv 3.4.3 me empezó a tirar este error al querer arrancar el programa, estuve revisando en la web pero aun no he encontrado alguna solución, alguna ayuda?

El error que me da

```
Starting /home/pi/Desktop/build-untitled2-Unnamed2-Debug/untitled2...

(untitled2:24186): Gtk-ERROR **: GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported
The program has unexpectedly finished.
/home/pi/Desktop/build-untitled2-Unnamed2-Debug/untitled2 crashed+66
```

Mi codigo en el .pro

```
QT       += core gui
#QT       += core
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x
#CPPFLAGS = -L/opencv-3.4.3/build/lib \
#            -I/opencv-3.4.3/build/include

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = untitled2
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0


SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/release/ -lueye_api
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/debug/ -lueye_api
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/ -lueye_api


unix: CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
unix: PKGCONFIG += gtk+-3.0


#INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv2
#INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv2
#DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include
#LIBS +=-L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lwiringPi -lopencv_photo -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_video -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_imgproc

#-libopencv_core.so.3.4.1
LIBS +=-L"/usr/local/lib" \
-lopencv_core -lwiringPi \
-lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs
```

Answer (score 1):

El error es muy claro:

> Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported

**No está soportado** el uso simultáneo de **ambas** versiones de las Gtk.

Simplemente, **quita la que no uses** de tu archivo `.pro`.

Comment: Lo raro es que aunque quite esto del .pro, ya sea el 2.0 o el 3.0 o quite ambas me sigue tirando ese error

Comment: Haz un `make clean` desde dentro de tu directorio Build, para eliminar archvos `.o` antiguos que tengan referencias a ambas.

Comment: Bueno, lo mejor sería borrar todo el contenido de Build y regenerar el proyecto ... hace mas de 1 año que no uso QTCreator ni QMake, la verdad es que no recuerdo las acciones exactas :-(

Comment: Es lo mas idea, que borres todo el contenido de Build, también quedan regazos de configuración donde trata de enlazar las dos librerías, lo mejor es limpiarla toda.

Comment: la de build esta ultima te refieres a la de opencv?

Comment: ya he  limpiado o borrado el contenido de build y esta regenerando el proyecto